# How to customize the appearance of OSM maps on Garmin GPS device?

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, garmin

Just downloaded my first OSM map onto my Garmin etrex 30x from http://garmin.openstreetmap.nl/.
I always liked the extremly fine level of detail of OSM, as compared to other maps I know it contains really about every dirt path there is.

The map I just downloaded is working fine, however there are a few details I'd like to change.

- There are **way to many points of interest** (grocery shops, gas stations, hairdressers etc.) marked on the map and I almost can't read anything. I'd like to delete these points category-wise (say, remove hairdressers but keep gas stations) to only keep what's relevant to me.
- I'd like to **change colors and line types of streets** (say, make all trails a fine black dotted line and all highways thick and purple).
- I'd like to **adjust which elements show at which zoom level** (say, only show trails when the area shown on screen is smaller than 20x20 meter).

Is there any software (preferably free) I can use to make these changes? Is there any website where I can customize these things before downloading? Or is there any other source of finely detailed maps I can use (relevant region is Central Europe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple questions you are posing:

**Is there any software (preferably free) I can use to make these changes?**

Yes. You can use [TYPwiz](https://www.pinns.co.uk/osm/typwiz5.html).

**Is there any website where I can customize these things before downloading?**

On the garmin.openstreetmap.nl website you can select 'include a typ' file. This slightly alters the appearance. to resemble that of [Mapnik](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik). Furthermore the openfietsmap.nl site also has a different layout. These are however, predefined and do not allow for the tailoring you ask for.

**Or is there any other source of finely detailed maps I can use (relevant region is Central Europe)?**

Not opensource/freeware by my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If this is still an issue to you, I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.thingsontwowheels.com/etrex-colors/) on how to change map colors using a Mac.

Quick summary:
I used PlayOnMac to install GMapTool and TYPViewer, but you can use CrossOver as well.

Comment: Could you please add details here instead of giving only a link?

Comment: I put in a quick summary, but it's too much information to put in here completely. If it's an issue or against your site policy, feel free to delete my post.

Answer (score 1):

Another prerendered dataset you can download and install into a Garmin extrex 30 is from the excellent [talkytoaster](https://talkytoaster.me.uk/) website

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I ended up using https://www.freizeitkarte-osm.de/garmin/de/index.html. There are nicely prepared maps of all countries that are immediately relevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

To stop auto zoom out when any feature is changed, go to views and turn on 3D.

Zoom will not be stable in the other two settings, Track Up or North Up that change zoom with screens selected.  Bad software programming is it.

Nuvi 2597LMT: dipped display in bleach while upgraded to 5.5 Garmim software.  Don't do a Garmin software update!